# Can not remove extension on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

Just as the following image, can not remove extension `Topicon`,

[image]

After I remove the folder in the gnome extension directory, it still show error.

```
➜  extensions pwd
/home/honhe/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
➜  extensions ll
total 32K
drwxrwxr-x 3 honhe honhe 4.0K Jan 18 20:04 appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 honhe honhe 4.0K Mar  1 15:28 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 honhe honhe 4.0K Jan 19 11:33 drop-down-terminal@gs-extensions.zzrough.org
drwxrwxr-x 4 honhe honhe 4.0K Jan 19 11:41 dynamicTopBar@gnomeshell.feildel.fr
drwxrwxr-x 3 honhe honhe 4.0K Jan 18 21:04 hide-legacy-tray@shell-extensions.jonnylamb.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 honhe honhe 4.0K Mar  1 15:28 netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 honhe honhe 4.0K Jan 31 18:41 nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr
drwxrwxr-x 3 honhe honhe 4.0K Jan 19 11:40 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

journalctl log:

```
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 3 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 4 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:47 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
Mar 23 10:11:48 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strer
Mar 23 10:11:48 iron gnome-session[3379]: (tracker-miner-fs:3546): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily
lines 20627-20683/20683 (END)
```

Comment: (1) What is the error when you hover the /!\ icon? (2) Have you restarted gnome-shell (`Alt + F2`, `r`)? (3) There's a good chance the tracker errors are unrelated

Comment: After reboot, it seems ok now.

Comment: @andy.holmes Why restart gnome-shell will not restart others apps such Chrome, Nautilous?

Comment: assuming `Alt + F2`, `r` worked you're probably running X11/Xorg instead of Wayland. In that case gnome-shell is acting more like a window manager instead of "the whole desktop" which is more like what it does in a Wayland session. Restarting gnome-shell in that case is usually safe to do and won't affect other programs (mostly).